# How to embed Apache Superset (v1.5) Dashboard in Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, apache-superset

I'm trying to embed an Apache 1.5 dashboard in a Wordpress site. So far I've succeeded in doing the following:

- Upgrade to Apache Superset 1.5 and enable the embedded dashboard functionality
- Configure dashboard to be embedded
- Implemented backend code to obtain JWT token

What I'm struggling with now is to implement the "@superset-ui/embedded-sdk" functionality in my Wordpress site (using TwentyTwentyOne standard template). I'm trying to follow the instructions listed here: https://fossies.org/dox/apache-superset-1.5.0-source/md_superset_embedded_sdk_README.html

The CDN approach looks the easiest, but I'm getting the error *ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined*. And if I add the following code:

`<script src="https://unpkg.com/buffer"></script>`

Then I get the error *ReferenceError: require is not defined*. I'm not sure how I can resolve this error. Is the CDN approach a dead end, or is there a way I can make this work?

With the "Using npm" approach I'm struggling even more. I'm able to install the npm packages on bitnami linux, but then I don't know how to make use of them in the site. I wasn't able to make it work to add '@superset-ui/embedded-sdk' using wp_enqueue_script(). Also I tried the following code in wordpress:

```
<script type="module">
import {embedDashboard} from 'http://[MY_IP_ADDRESS]/wp-content/themes/twentytwentyone/node_modules/@superset-ui/embedded-sdk/lib/index.js';
</script>
```

However then I get the following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module 'http://[MY_IP_ADDRESS]/wp-content/themes/twentytwentyone/node_modules/@superset-ui/embedded-sdk/lib/index.js' does not provide an export named 'embedDashboard'

I don't quite understand this error as embedDashboard does appear to be defined in the js file. I also tried using the embedded-sdk/bundle/index.js file with the same result.

I've spent many hours on this and I'm not sure what approach I should take. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Or even better: have a solution to a similar problem with sample code I can look at? If I need to provide more details on what I've tried or what errors I'm seeing let me know.

Answer (score 2):

### This is how I did it.
I wrote my backend in Flask.
**My Superset Version is 2.0**

backend.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify 
import requests 
import json 
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/') 
def hello():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route("/guest-token", methods=["GET"])
def guest_token():
    url = "http://<IP>:<PORT>/api/v1/security/login" 
    payload = json.dumps({ "password": "<>", "provider": "db", "refresh": "true", "username": "<>" })
    headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json' }

    responsel = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload) 
    print(responsel.text)
    superset_access_token = json.loads(responsel.text)['access_token']
    payload = json.dumps ({ 
        "user": {
            "username": "kashew",
            "first name":"Kashish", 
            "lastname":"Bakshi"
        },
        
        "resources": [{
            "type": "dashboard",
            "id": "8f96cc84-7e9e-4f5c-ba92-3a1f0825fe3d"
        }],
        "rls": []
    })
               
    bearer_token = "Bearer " + superset_access_token
    print(bearer_token)
    response2 = requests.post(
         "http://<IP>:<PORT>/api/v1/security/guest_token", 
         data = payload,
         headers = { "Authorization": bearer_token, 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }) 
    print(response2.json())
    return jsonify(response2.json()['token'])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**Explanation:**
The Major part of understanding is the Guest_Token Function.

**Here two POST Requests are at play.**

1. The first Request gets the access token from Superset.
2. The Second request uses the Access Token we got as Bearer and is a POST Call to get the Guest_Token from Superset.

**Payload for Guest_Token:**

```
{ 
        "user": {
            "username": "kashew",
            "first name":"Kashish", 
            "lastname":"Bakshi"
        },
        
        "resources": [{
            "type": "dashboard",
            "id": "8f96cc84-7e9e-4f5c-ba92-3a1f0825fe3d"
        }],
        "rls": []
    }
```

**Explanation:**
The Payload is a JSON with 3 Key-Value Pair.

- user (Here, I created a Dummy User{ **This can be replaced with your App Auth Logic**})
- resources (Refer [this](https://medium.com/@khushbu.adav/embedding-superset-dashboards-in-your-react-application-7f282e3dbd88#:%7E:text=Generate%20Embedded%20dashboard%20uuid,use%20an%20Embedded%20Dashboard%20UUID.))
- rls (I kept it empty but more can be found [here](https://docs.preset.io/docs/step-2-deployment))

I ran my backend on Localhost:5000.

For Frontend, I created a directory "templates" and put my index.html file inside it.

index.html

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@superset-ui/embedded-sdk"></script>
    <style>
      iframe {
        width: 100%;
        height: 50%;
        border: none;

        pretext {
          margin-right: 10%;
          margin-left: 10%;
          font-family: Tahoma;
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="pretext">
      <h2> Covid Statistics </h2>
      <p> Dive into Covid data
      <p id="dashboard-container"></p>
      <script>
        async function fetchGuestTokenFromBackend() {
            let response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/guest-token');
            let data = await response.json()
            return data 
        }

            const myDashboard = supersetEmbeddedSdk.embedDashboard({
              id: "8f96cc84-7e9e-4f5c-ba92-3a1f0825fe3d",
              supersetDomain: "http://<IP>:<PORT>",
              mountPoint: document.getElementById("dashboard-container"),
              fetchGuestToken: () => fetchGuestTokenFromBackend(),
              dashboardUiConfig: {
                hideTitle: true,
                hideChartControls: true
              },
            });
      </script>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Explanation:**
It calls my guest-token method which returns a Guest-Token to my frontend. The Frontend then makes a request to Superset Embed Dashboard URL with the guest-token which in turn embeds and renders the chart in an Iframe on my website.

Answer (score 0):

**Hello, I hope this example of using 'superset embedded-sdk' will help you:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    ...
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@superset-ui/embedded-sdk"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="dashboard" width="700" height="700"></p>
        <script>
            async function getToken() {
                const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/token');
                const data = await res.json()
                console.log(data['value']);
                return data['value'];
            }
    
            supersetEmbeddedSdk.embedDashboard({
                id: "7b5ee110-435b-4ad1-a257-97ea340bf82d",
                supersetDomain: "http://localhost:8088",
                mountPoint: document.getElementById("dashboard"),
                fetchGuestToken: () => getToken(),
                dashboardUiConfig: {
                    hideTitle: true,
                    filters: {
                        expanded: true
                    }
                }
            });
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).